# ag-grid lock group expanded

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm looking to lock a group as expanded if a member of the group has been selected. It seems like ag grid doesn't offer this capability at all, but I wanted to ask in case I missed anything.

The available fields/methods I have explored are

```
node.expanded
node.isExpandable
node.setExpanded
```

None of these allow you to disable the collapse function, they only allow you to disable the expansion thereafter.